# Google Drive resumable upload using Salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning, upload, google-drive

I have been trying to upload a large file (maybe greater than 25MB) from Salesforce lightning to Google drive, referencing - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable

However, I wasn't able to successfully complete it. Two questions -

1. What is the maximum file size Salesforce lightning can handle for upload?
2. Has anyone tried resumable Google drive upload?